# Is there a windows unicode-only collation?

Tags: sql-server, unicode, sql-server-2014, collation

I am trying to get my head around Unicode and Collations and how to use collations properly in ms sql server 2014.
[Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175835(v=sql.120).aspx%20) states:

"Windows Unicode-only collations can only be used with the `COLLATE` clause to apply collations to the `nchar, nvarchar, and ntext` data types on column level and expression-level data. They cannot be used with the `COLLATE` clause to change the collation of a database or server instance."

What Windows unicode-only collations are? I want to convert my database to support unicode so now  I use only nvarchar, nchar and ntext. I did `SELECT * FROM sys.fn_helpcollations()` and I got a list of collations. None of them is described as Unicode-only collation.  That's where I am getting confused, if there is a unicode only collation as microsoft states how can I find it and what's the logic behind it?

Comment: Off topic; from the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187993.aspx): ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

Answer (score 0):

use this to get collations with codepage is 0, should be the unicode-only collations.

`select name, COLLATIONPROPERTY(name, 'CodePage') as CodePage, description
from sys.fn_HelpCollations() order by code_page
go`